# Creating an SSIS package that uses a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dts

We're trying to make an SSIS package where it'll launch a stored procedure and capture the contents in a flat file. This will have to run every night, and the new file should overwrite the existing file.

This wouldn't normally be a problem, as we just plug in the query and it runs, but this time everything was complicated enough that we chose to approach it with a stored procedure employing temporary tables. How can I go about using this in a DTS package? I tried going the normal route with the Wizard and then plugging in `EXEC BlahBlah.dbo...` It did not care for that:

> The Statement could not be parsed. Additional information: Invalid
>   object name '#DestinyDistHS'. (Microsoft SQL Server Native Client
>   10.0)

Can anyone guide me in the right direction here?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry -- old terminology floating around the workplace. We are working with SSIS.

I'm picking this up as I go so I just ended up using the term I heard in the office.

Comment: in your stored procedure try `SET FMTONLY OFF;SET NOCOUNT ON`. Also at the package level - set the package property to use `Delayed validation = TRUE`. That should help you.

Comment: Okay. I did everything listed. I changed ValidateExternalMetadata to False (did not see a direct reference to Delayed Validation)... Everything looked like it was going to work, but when I tried hitting okay to get out of the OLE DB Source Editor, I got a Microsoft Visual Studio Error: Eror at Data Flow Task... Again, "Invalid Object Name '#Destiny...'"

Comment: Are you defining the temp table inline or with a SELECT INTO statement?  If you're using SELECT INTO, try doing a CREATE/INSERT setup instead.  The problem is that SSIS is trying to parse the table and since it can't find a schema it can't build metadata.  @Kin's suggestion to delay validataion will work but only once you have metadata actually assigned the first time 'round, in design mode.

Comment: Oh! Go to the properties for the Data Flow Task itself to set Delay Validation to true.

Comment: Valkyrie, you mentioning the Data Flow Task helped -- I made the changed as described. It still won't let me plug in EXEC storedprocedure name when I attempted to edit the Data Flow Task.

And yes: The stored procedure did CREATE the tables and then INSERTed data into them.
INSER INTO #TempT
SELECT...

I'm sorry about sounding like a total idiot, but I'm a total newbie.

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling the temp table from a different task try this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631010/how-to-create-a-temporary-table-in-ssis-control-flow-task-and-then-use-it-in-dat